# ImageButton onClick never triggered

Tags: android, xml, onclicklistener

My `OnClickListener` is never triggered, I have tried to create listener for this button only, then as it is now implemented `OnClickListener`. `initToolbarAndDrawerWithReadableName` method is invoked in child class as `this.initToolbarAndDrawerWithReadableName`. What i did wrong?

Toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/end"
    android:gravity="center|end"
    android:id="@+id/auth_toolbar"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_button"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_active"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Init toolbar

```
 protected void initToolbarAndDrawerWithReadableName(String title) {

        toolbarTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.toolbarTv);
        toolbarTv.setText(title);
        toolbarTv.setOnClickListener(this);

        View child = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, null);

        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        nvDrawer.addHeaderView(child);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.auth_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

        imageButton = (ImageButton) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.drawer_button);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

OnClick:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("click","i am here");
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.drawer_button:{
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.toolbarTv:{
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting the "i am here" message on your log cat?

Comment: I suspect you didn't call the `super` class method in the child class

Comment: @PeterChaula So did i, it was the first thing i checked. I have invoked it.

Comment: I tried your code in an empty activity, the `drawer_button` onClick is working as expected.

Comment: @MohanadMohie I used it like 6 month for now in to projects, but it isnt working in this concrete one =).

Comment: There must be something in the rest of the code that is causing it to misbehave, something you might have missed or something. Unfortunately, with the data provided in the question, it is working for me, so I can't be of any help. Also, try to Clean then Rebuild the project, sometimes that's all it takes to solve a weird code misbehavior.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your xml file you have only define **ImageButton**, No TextView for **toolbarTv** and also no click method which is defined for switch statement.

**Try**

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTv"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTv"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: I have deleted the textView from xml, cause stackowerflow was telling me that i have too much code, but there is Tv in xml, and i have switch for Iv and Tv.

Comment: have you added 
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:clickable="true"
in imageButton and TextView both?

Comment: Yes i have tried to add only one line, and both of them together.

Comment: can you paste the textView from xml for toolbarTv in comment ?

Comment: Here we goes
       <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTv"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drawer_button"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/drawer_button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />

Comment: Exxactly what I though the textView does not have attributes of onClick and clicable defined please see the below code




 <TextView android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginStart="20dp" android:id="@+id/toolbarTv" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drawer_button" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/drawer_button" 
android:onClick="onClick"
android:clickable="true"
android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of cod to your xml. It will call the onClick method you made every time the button is pressed

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

try making your xml look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/end"
    android:gravity="center|end"
    android:id="@+id/auth_toolbar"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_active"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:clickable="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

make sure you onClick class is in the activity, but not in any other activities. ex

```
main activity{

create(){}

other(){}

onClick(){}

otherOther(){}

}
```

also, comment out the method that declares the listener for now and see if it works, it works for me

Comment: did you add it within the image button?

Comment: @hankTheCowDog I don't think that is a good idea. You 're doing the same thing twice by `android:onClick="onClick"`. If you choose the interface then go with it. If you choose the declaration in xml then exclusively go with that

Comment: Yes i have added it to the ImageButton

Comment: I see it says android:clickable="true", but the easiest way to tell when a View is pressed, and it is created in XML is to use the above line of code. With the onClick in "" being the name of the method you wish to call. It just happens that the method he wishes to call is called onClick

Comment: @PeterChaula I understand this, but i am just trying to fix it(prefare to do it in code), xml onClick is not realy an option, i tried it just to understand will it work this way.

Comment: I personally don't like doing it this way, I bet it would work if it is done the above way, and much simpler in my opinion. @Peter Chaula

Comment: Is the method within another method? if it is that would be why it isn't working.

Comment: It should be in the main activity class, but not contained within anything else ex, main{    other method{} onClick{} otherOtherMethod{} }

Comment: @hankTheCowDog I have tried it both ways, but it doesnt work anyway.

Comment: @hankTheCowDog Why it should be in mainactivity class =)? It can be in parrent class/it maybe done as a callback and so on. This method of duing this is working great on 2 my other projects but not on this o_o.Thats the problem.

Comment: There's a long explanation that I'm not 100% sure if I will get right, but you need to know is based on the way the magical engineers at google created android they decided to make it so that the onClick looks for the onClick method you specify in the current activity you are in, which I assume is the main activity; however, if you're in a different activity when you want the button pressed the onClick method must be in that activity

Comment: @hankTheCowDog  MainActivity extends BaseActivity, BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity. It also works this way =).

Comment: :/ well, I have no idea then. All I can do is say try this the way I said, and if it doesn't work hopefully someone clever reads this. My one last suggestion is to try copying the xml I put then paste it over your xml to see if my guess is right. If it doesn't work hit control z after that will undo it.

Comment: also once the xml has been changed comment out these two lines and see what happens imageButton = (ImageButton) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.drawer_button);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(this); I am currious

Comment: It will take a min, I'll modify my answer, and then you can try it

Comment: actually, has initToolbarAndDrawerWithReadableName been run? this could be the problem

Comment: put a log in it to check

Comment: @hankTheCowDog     Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.initToolbarAndDrawerWithReadableName("Дарова");
    }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting click listener to ImageButton, add it to parent RelativeLayout because here parent is intercepting the click event.

Comment: If i will do so, i will have all the toolbar clickable, but i need only the button click

Answer (score 0):

use Butter Knife [Link Tutorial](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) and  [GitHub Simple](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife),

1) add this to your dependencies

```
       compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
       apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

2) add this to your dependencies in build.gradle

```
       apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
       apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
```

befor

```
       apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

add

```
       apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
       apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
```

3) add this in your Activity

```
      @BindView(R.id.drawer_button) ImageButton drawer_button;
```

4) then add

```
     @OnClick(R.id.drawer_button)
      public void openDrawer() {
       mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
       }
```